FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X6711 in debug mode...
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.


Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
> Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             44.3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I can't run my project.

An error message is a good start, but more debugging details would make this a much better question. Information such as versions, an [mre], OS, etc. could be helpful.
